# AngularJS, get data from external source and push into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call an external scrip that gets data from a database, so I can then populate a select dropdown. I've tried this so far, but I get a load of empty `li` elements. It is the right count of what there should be just nothing showing?

**My controller**

```
app.controller('agenciesController', function($scope, $http) {
  var url = "/ajax/getAgencies.php";

  $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
    $scope.agencies = response; 
    $scope.agenciesArray = [];
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key){
      $scope.agenciesArray.push(value);
    })
    console.log($scope.agenciesArray);
  });
})
```

My HTML

```
<body ng-controller="Controller">
   <div ng-controller="agenciesController">
      <ul ng-repeat="agencyName in agencies">
        <li>{{agenciesArray.agencyID}}</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**  -
This code is working but not returning only one response but all.

```
  <div ng-controller="agenciesController">
    <ul ng-repeat="agencyName in agenciesArray">
      <li>{{agencyName}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add sample response

Comment: agenciesArray is an array. agenciesArray.agencyID will be undefined. that is why you are gettting empty li.

Comment: Your ng-repeat loops on $scope.agencies but in the li you have agenciesArray.agencyID that I don't know what can be

Answer (score 4):

agenciesArray is an array. agenciesArray.agencyID will be undefined. that is why you are gettting empty li.

Do you intend to do this?

```
<ul ng-repeat="agency in agenciesArray">
        <li>{{agency.agencyName}}</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: This is bringing stuff back but not just agencyName by its self check edit.

Comment: good one you have to check for the attribute agencyName in the object that you called agencyName in th eng-repeat

Comment: @rick so basically in ng-repeat it's like assigning a variable to agenciesArray

Comment: Just another question, how can I put these as `<select>` options instead of in a ul?

Comment: The syntax is "iterator in list"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul ng-repeat="agencyName in agencies">
    <li>{{agencyName.agencyID}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Reason:Because agencyArray is nothing in the given context